# does this indicates that tensorflow uses cpu instead of gpu? :I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:112] CPU Frequency: 1497600000 Hz

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, nvidia, tensor

Im using nvidia gpu but tensorflow is still using cpu although it can see the gpu

```
023-03-07 19:41:14.501723: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49]           Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1 
    [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
    2023-03-07 19:41:15.203053: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA     devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
    2023-03-07 19:41:15.203588: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49]   Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
    2023-03-07 19:41:15.228659: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941]   successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA   node, so returning NUMA node zero
    2023-03-07 19:41:15.228834: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found  device 0 with properties: 
    pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce MX110 computeCapability: 5.0
    coreClock: 1.006GHz coreCount: 2 deviceMemorySize: 1.96GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 37.33GiB/s
    2023-03-07 19:41:15.228852: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49]     Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
    2023-03-07 19:41:15.229990: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
    2023-03-07 19:41:15.230025: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.10
    2023-03-07 19:41:15.231148: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
    2023-03-07 19:41:15.231351: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
    2023-03-07 19:41:15.232379: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
    2023-03-07 19:41:15.232920: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
    2023-03-07 19:41:15.235052: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
    2023-03-07 19:41:15.235158: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA   node, so returning NUMA node zero
    2023-03-07 19:41:15.235414: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA   node, so returning NUMA node zero
    2023-03-07 19:41:15.235533: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0

    # when arriving to model.fit

    2023-03-07 19:43:41.793302: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
    2023-03-07 19:43:41.811353: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:112] CPU  Frequency: 1497600000 Hz
    2023-03-07 19:43:41.855519: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49]   Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
```

[image]

nvcc version
nvcc:  11.5, V11.5.119

gcc version
gcc  11.3.0

- tensorflow=2.4.1 tensorflow_gpu=2.4.1 python=3.9.16
  cudatoolkit=10.1.243  cudnn=7.6.5

Any solution to solve my issue please. I google it for a long time without any result.
thank you in advance

Comment: What evidence do you have that its using the CPU only? I don't see anything relevant in  your question.

Comment: thank you for your comment. This message : CPU  Frequency: 1497600000 Hz. also by monitoring gpu utilization when running the code : 0%. Finaly the speed of the execution of the same code when I excute it in other machine using gpu

Comment: None of these are hard indicators of GPU not being used, maybe your model is too simple or you made another mistake, if you are not compute bound, then using GPUs will not make anything faster. Note that CPU is always used, GPUs do not work independent of the CPU.

Comment: My code is about RL agent. Is not simple. Also as sais I run the same code in other pc with gpu and it was very faster

Comment: Then add all details, we cannot guess details that are not in the question. I can even see that the log is edited as there are incomplete parts, like: [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')] Everything indicates that the GPU is detected and used by TensorFlow.

Comment: so why this message CPU Frequency: 1497600000 Hz. this is the first time that I see such messaage when I use gpu

Comment: You are seeing patterns in randomness. The CPU freq message is always printed because the CPU can always be used.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue. I tried with other code, the GPU works perfectly. So I guessed that the problem is in my code. So I checked it and I fixed the issue.